# Subquery with linq

Tags: sql, linq

I want to do a subquery with linq but it doesn't work. :-( I've searched google for an answer, but I don't know how to solve the problem.

This is my sql

```
string strSQL = @"SELECT a.ident, a.ben1 
                FROM pwdata a 
                WHERE a.iid = (SELECT max(b.iid) FROM pwdata b WHERE b.ident = a.ident)";
```

That's how I tried to do with Linq, but this is not the right way

```
var query = from i in maxxContext.pwdata
            where i.IID = (SELECT max(b.iid) FROM pwdata b WHERE b.ident = a.ident) 
            orderby i.ident

            select new CompareParts
            {
                PartNumber = i.ident,
                PartName = i.ben1
            };
            return query.ToList().Distinct();
```

Can anyone of you help me?

Comment: Query the max value into a temporary variable and then use it in your final query.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you've started intermingling LINQ with regular SQL. It doesn't work like that.

This should work though:

```
var query = from i in maxxContext.pwdata
            where i.IID == (pwdata.Where(b => b.ident == i.ident)
                                  .Max(b => b.iid))
            orderby i.ident
            select new CompareParts
            {
                PartNumber = i.ident,
                PartName = i.ben1
            };
```

Alternatively, you could do a join:

```
var query = from i in maxxContext.pwdata
            join b in pwdata on i.ident equals b.ident into bs
            where i.IID == bs.Max(b => b.iid)
            orderby i.ident
            select new CompareParts
            {
                PartNumber = i.ident,
                PartName = i.ben1
            };
```

Comment: var query = from i in maxxContext.pwdata
                                where i.IID == (maxxContext.pwdata.Where(b => b.ident == i.ident)
                                                      .Max(b => b.IID))
                                orderby i.ident
                                select new CompareParts
                                {
                                    PartNumber = i.ident,
                                    PartName = i.ben1
                                };

Comment: @Jocelyn: Well that's given us no more information about what's wrong. I can't help without more information. If you're presenting more code, I suggest you edit your question - comments aren't good for presenting code.

Comment: My query hast no entries => is null

Comment: I always get an timeout error ... :-( Are you sure, that the linq query is corret?

Comment: @Jocelyn: Well you should look at what's happening at the query level. Try adding logging, so you can see what queries are being executed.

Comment: Ok, but how can I see or do that? With debugging? Or with an tool for the database?

Comment: @Jocelyn: If this is LINQ to SQL, your context should have a `Log` property.